# Get test class name within static context from it's parent

Tags: java, junit, playframework, static

Currently I am trying to get the class name of any underlying class which inherits from BaseTest, within static context. So for explanation I am writing a base-class
which does use the `@BeforeClass` of junit. The problem here is I am starting a fake application before all the tests of the class, with it's own in memory h2 database. I want to name the database as the test class, so I can later see what was written to the database per test.

BaseTest:

```
public abstract class BaseTest {
private static final Map<String, String> testConfig = getTestConfig();
private static FakeApplication fakeApplication;

@BeforeClass
public static void onlyOnce(){
    fakeApplication = Helpers.fakeApplication(testConfig);
    Helpers.start(fakeApplication);
}

@AfterClass
public static void afterClass(){
    Helpers.stop(fakeApplication);
    fakeApplication = null;
}

private static Map<String, String> getTestConfig() {
    //Here should bee FooTest in this case! But actually it's BaseTest
    String className = MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getSimpleName();
    ...
    configs.put("db.default.url", "jdbc:h2:file:./data/tests/" + className  + ";AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
}
```

And for example some child test:

```
public class FooTest extends BaseTest{
     @Test 
     public void testFoo(){
     }
}
```

I already tried several things and as far as I know it's not posssible. 
But I just need to ask if there's anything I don't know yet.

Comment: You may use a specific `TestRule` for this

Comment: I already tried:

@Rule
    public TestRule watcher = new TestWatcher() {
        protected void starting(Description description) {
            System.out.println("Starting test: " + description.getMethodName());
        }
    };

Comment: Static members belong only to the class where they are declared in. They have nothing to do with subclassing! What you are trying to do can only be achieved with non-static members.

Comment: What about @ClassRule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution using '@ClassRule' and implemting a customg `TestWatcher`. As the `starting(Description description)` is called before the `@BeforeClass public static void beforeClass()` method I can use it like this:

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class BaseTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static CustomTestWatcher classWatcher = new CustomTestWatcher();
    private static Map<String, String> testConfig;
    private static FakeApplication fakeApplication;    


    public static class CustomTestWatcher extends TestWatcher {
        private String className = BaseTest.class.getSimpleName();

        public String getClassName() {
            return className;
        }

        private void setClassName(String className) {
            this.className = className;
        }

        @Override
        protected void starting(Description description) {
            //This will set className to = FooTest!
            setClassName(description.getClassName());
            System.out.println("\nStarting test class: " + className);
        }
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        //Here now finally is FooTest!
        String className = classWatcher.getClassName();
        System.out.println("Creating Test Database and Fake Application for " + className);
        ...
    }
```